# Woocommerce change add to cart text if stock status is 0

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I'm trying to check if a product is at 0 stock, and if so, change the text on the cart button. I don't want to check if they're out of stock because backorders are allowed so products will never be out of stock, they'll stop at 0. What am I missing from this code?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
    global $product;
    $product->get_stock_quantity();

    if( $product == 0 ) {
        return __( 'Backorder', 'woocommerce' );
    } else {
        return __( 'Add to cart ', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
```

Comment: use `if( $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 )`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability', 'custom_get_stock', 1, 2);
function custom_get_stock( $availability, $_product ) {
if ( !$_product->is_in_stock() ) $availability['availability'] = __('Backorder', 'woocommerce');
return $availability;
}
```